# Retrieving all code between 2 XML tags from the DOM Parser

Tags: xml, dom

I'm trying to do this on php, The XML I'm trying to parse looks like this --

```
<a name="A">text</a>
<p class=A>text</p>
<p class=A>text</p>
<p class=A>text</p>
<p class=B>text</p>
<p class=B>text</p>
<a name="B">TEXT</a>
```

please how can i get all code between `<a name="A">text</a>` and `<a name="B">TEXT</a>`

Comment: That isn't a well-formed XML document. There must be a single root element.

Comment: i know but i can't change it :-(

Comment: In that case, if you want to handle it as XML, you're going to have to do so by wrappering it in another XML document -- either via text processing (set up a stream which precedes it with <doc> and follows it with </doc> or by treating it as an External Parsed Entity and creating a document which imports it that way (requires playing with DTDs). If you don't do one of those, the DOM parser will reject it as Not Well-Formed.

Or you could give up and process it as text which resembles, but isn't, XML.

Comment: You might want to be more specific in your question. With the given parameters you could (1) select line 2 through 6, (2) use an XPATH selector on all p-elements, (3) use a regex for lines containing the text class, (4) find the index of the specified start and end text-elements and do a substring between them and...